# How I can create a table having two long columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I am using Oracle 10 g.

I have a table which needs two columns of the `Long` type:

```
CREATE TABLE emp
 (
    id1 LONG NULL,
    id2 LONG NULL,
    //
    // Other columns.
);
```

When I am executing this query, it is giving me this error:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01754: a table may contain only one column of type LONG
01754. 00000 -  "a table may contain only one column of type LONG"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to add a LONG column to a table which already
           had a LONG column. Note that even if the LONG column currently
           in the table has already been marked unused, another LONG column
           may not be added until the unused columns are dropped.
*Action:   Remove the LONG column currently in the table by using the ALTER
           TABLE command.
```

I searched on Google, but I could not find a proper solution. Why do they not allow two columns of `LONG`?

Is using `number` instead of a column a good idea?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you're already modifying the Quartz tables, you may also want to change VARCHAR to VARCHAR2.  Their table scripts have a few issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LONG` columns have not been recommended for a long time; since 8i, I believe. From [the 11g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref138):

> Do not create tables with LONG columns. Use LOB columns (CLOB, NCLOB,
>   BLOB) instead. LONG columns are supported only for backward
>   compatibility.

You were only ever allowed one `LONG` column in a table. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that was because the `LONG` data was stored alongside the other columns, and more than one would make it even more unmanageable. LOBs are stored differently; see the table [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_tables.htm#i1006208) for a comparison.

---

Oracle's [`LONG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i54330) datatype is 'Character data of variable length up to 2 gigabytes'. If you're storing numeric data, use `NUMBER`.

If you're mapping Java data types (guessing from your profile!), [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/datacc.htm#BHCJBJCC) may be of use.

Comment: Which one either of these is the best to use for long? And how i can get the long value back from this Datatypes?

Comment: @vikiiii - maybe this is a complete datatype mismatch; are you trying to find a datatype that matches something like a `C` `long`, which is numeric? I'm guessing from the column names looking like IDs. Oracle's `LONG` is completely different...

Comment: yes. My columns are numeric. Is using `number` instead of a column is a good idea?? Or any other datatype which i can use

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 8i the LONG datatype is advised not to be used and instead use CLOB or NLOB datatypes.

Just in case check [Oracle 10g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements001.htm) about datatypes. Also [check here for other details](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/LONG)